# javascript code to open new window on every click is replacing the old window and creates new blank window

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to open new window on every click on a href link.
But The window gets replaced with the value of new page only and one blank window gets opened on every click. I've tried samples told in many examples but no use.

Here is the sample code segment..

```js
var mapForm = document.createElement("form");
     mapForm.target = "Map";
     mapForm.method = "POST"; // or "post" if appropriate
     mapForm.action = "../TestWindowsSample.jsp";

     var mapInput = document.createElement("input");
     mapInput.type = "hidden";
     mapInput.name = "selectedId";
     mapInput.value = selectedId;
     mapForm.appendChild(mapInput);
     document.body.appendChild(mapForm);

     map = window.open("", "Map"+(windowCount++), "status=0,title=0,height=600,width=800,scrollbars=1");

 if (map) {
     mapForm.submit();
 } else {
     alert('You must allow popups for this map to work.');
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You now only have one target, `"Map"`

Also I assume `selectedId` and `windowCount`are set somewhere else, right?

Try

```
var windowCount = 0;
var selectedId = "some string";
var mapForm;
.
.
.
mapForm = document.createElement("form");
var tgt = "Map" + (windowCount++); // define the target here
mapForm.target = tgt;
mapForm.method = "POST"; // or "post" if appropriate
mapForm.action = "http://www.zensolutions.co.nz/dev/httpdump";
var mapInput = document.createElement("input");
mapInput.type = "hidden";
mapInput.name = "selectedId";
mapInput.value = selectedId + tgt; // is this set somewhere?
mapForm.appendChild(mapInput);
document.body.appendChild(mapForm);
map = window.open("", tgt,"height=600,width=800,scrollbars"); // reuse target here
if (map) {
  setTimeout(function() { // give IE time to respond
    mapForm.submit();
  }, 10);
} else {
  alert('You must allow popups for this map to work.');
}
```

PS: If you are using jQuery it is quite easy to show a div and replace the content of the div with the result of a post.

Comment: Ya you are right. selectedId is set somewhere in my code and I've tried with the way you said. Same result no change. Why is it one empty/blank window is getting opened??

Comment: I would have to see it in action. What browser? Any message in the console? Is windowCount defined as an int?